# Subset around values that follow a pattern

Tags: r, regex

Hopefully, this is a fairly straight forward question. I am using R to help subset some data that I am working with. Below is `print()` of some of the data that I am currently working with. I am trying to create a `subset()` of the data based around `JobCode`. As you can see the JobCode follows a pattern (00 - 0000) where the first 2 numbers are the same for a specific industry.

```
          ID   State         StateName JobCode
          1    AL            Alabama   51-9199
          2    AL            Alabama   27-3011
          4    AL            Alabama   49-9043
          5    AL            Alabama   49-2097
```

My current attempt is to use this `test <- subset(data, data$State == "AL" & data$JobCode == ("15-####"))`(where # is a placeholder for the remaining 4 values) to subset for JobCode beginning with "15-". Is there any way to tell the subset to look for those remaining 4 values?

I'm sorry for the poor formatting as I am new to StackOverflow and I am also quite inexperienced with R. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For patterns in text, regular expressions can handle it (whether using R or anything else). Type `?regex` at the console for R's docs. Alternately, if the start is always fixed-width, you can look at `?substring`.

Comment: @Frank thank you for pointing me towards the `?regex` that helped my knowledge on the topic immensely. I'm still learning all the syntax nuances of R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no wild card characters in string equality. You need to use a function. You could use `substr()` to extract the first three charcters

```
test <- subset(data, State == "AL" & substr(JobCode,1,3) == ("15-"))
```

Also note that you don't need to use `data$` inside the `subset()` parameter. Variables are evaulated in the context of the data frame for that function.

Comment: Great, thank you very much @MrFlick. That worked. That you for sharing about `data$` callout as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `%like%` operator of `data.table` library:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[ State == "AL" & JobCode %like% "15-" ]
```